# How to solve haskell tree prorder

Tags: haskell, tree

Can anybody help me solve the problem. I am new to haskell and have no idea of this problem.

> Consider the following data type.
>
> ```
> data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
>               | Leaf a
> ```
>
> **Problem 7. (10 points)** Implement the two functions that traverse the tree in the given order collecting the values from the tree nodes
>   into a list:
>
> ```
> preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
> inorder  :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
> ```
>
> Notice that the data type `Tree` can store different types of values
>   in the leaves than on the branching nodes. Thus, each of these
>   functions takes two functions as arguments: The first function maps
>   the values stored in the leaves to some common type `c`, and the
>   second function maps the values stored in the branching nodes to type
>   `c`, thus, resulting in a list of type `[c]`.

So far I have tried the following, but don't know how to test my answers:

```
preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c] 
preorder f g (Leaf x)= [f x] 
preorder f g (Branch x l r) = g x : (preorder f g l ++ preorder f g r) 

inorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c] 
inorder f g (Leaf x) = [f x] 
inorder f g (Branch x l r) = inorder f g l ++ [g x] ++ inorder f g r
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having problems?

Comment: preorder  :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
preorder f g (Leaf x)= [f x]
preorder f g (Branch x l r) = g x : (preorder f g l ++ preorder f g r)

inorder   :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c]
inorder f g (Leaf x) = [f x]
inorder f g (Branch x l r) = inorder f g l ++ [g x]++ inorder f g r

Comment: i don't know how to test my answers

Comment: Those look correct. What have you tried to test? In what ways is it giving  you trouble? Please provide exactly what you've tried and the full text of any error messages you get.

Comment: I just don't know how to test whether it's correct. What parameters should i put in the function to test it?

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have provided looks correct. To test, here is a nifty little example:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tree-traversals-inorder-preorder-and-postorder/

The representation for this tree might be something like this:

```
tree :: Tree Int Int
tree = Branch 1 (Branch 2 (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5)) (Leaf 3)
```

Here both the leaves and internal nodes are of type `Int`.

Now the `preorder` and `inorder` functions take two additional functions `f` and `g` of type `(a -> c)` and `(b -> c)` respectively, which are ways of converting the data in the leaves from type `a` to some type `c` and the data from internal branches from type `b` to `c`. These are two functions that you would have to supply yourself, depending on what your desired output type `c` is.

For instance, let us consider a complete example of `Tree Int String`. We pass in two functions `intToStr` and `strToStr` as ways of converting the leaves and internal nodes' data to our desired output type: `String`:

```
 data Tree a b = Branch b (Tree a b) (Tree a b)
               | Leaf a

 tree :: Tree Int String
 tree = Branch "one" (Branch "two" (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5)) (Leaf 3)

 preorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c] 
 preorder f g (Leaf x)= [f x] 
 preorder f g (Branch x l r) = g x : (preorder f g l ++ preorder f g r) 

 inorder :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Tree a b -> [c] 
 inorder f g (Leaf x) = [f x]
 inorder f g (Branch x l r) = inorder f g l ++ [g x] ++ inorder f g r

 strToStr :: String -> String
 strToStr s = s

 intToStr :: Int -> String
 intToStr i = show i

 main = do
     if (preorder intToStr strToStr tree == ["one", "two", "4", "5", "3"]) &&
        (inorder intToStr strToStr tree  == ["4", "two", "5", "one", "3"])
         then putStrLn "Correct implementation!"
         else putStrLn "Something went wrong :("
```